# Grails controllers redirect and SEO

Tags: grails, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I am not sure my question makes sense. I have read everything I could on the subject but it did not answered my interrogation.

So here it is: I know search engines do not consider temporary redirects, with 302 status. 
They do not pass any *link juice* in redirecting one page to another. 
This is not the case for 301 status redirects.

Grails default all its redirects to 302 status.

My question is:
Does that affect SEO in any bad way, or not at all ?

I am speaking about controllers' redirects here, when handling action calls. As it is not the change of one page location to another, but just the way users move into the application, should I care about what kind of redirect is issued by my controllers actions ?

Any bit of explanation is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally redirects (302) are used in response to some user input, for example a user post a form and the controller redirect to a different page based on form input.
If this is your scenario you have not to worry about SEO, search engine never compile forms.
But if you use grails controller redirect as a default navigation system for your app this is wrong. In the web every page may have a unique uri so a search engine can find it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect the search engine rankings, if you properly include canonical tag and set up preferred domain in Google webmaster tools